# Android Chronometer: Stops when changing View - Save state?

Tags: android, chronometer

I've got a ActionBar via ActionBarSherlock, but when I switch from the tab of the chrono, to another. It stops and goes back to 0. When I minimize the app it doesn't stop...

What do I need to save the state? I'm using 4 Button for start, stop, resume, and restart...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running the timer in the the UI thread. The UI thread is stopped when you move on to another view.
Try using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and put the job in background so it runs even if you leave the view itself.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I have but you can check this. http://github.com/jwood/standup-timer